# Find probability that a newborn weighs between $6$ and $8$ pounds; given mean and standard deviation but not given sample size

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation, means

The weight of a newborn baby randomly sampled from a particular population of babies is known to be normally distributed with a population mean weight of $7.25$ pounds and a population standard deviation of $2$ pounds.

If a baby is randomly sampled from this population, what is the probability that the baby weighs between $6$ and $8$ pounds?

Normally I am used to solving them by using $\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma / \sqrt{n}}$ and plugging in $6$ and $8$ and finding the values with the chart, but I am not given $n$ (sample size) in this problem. So is this problem not solvable since there is not enough information or is there another approach to finding the answer?

Comment: "A (single) baby is sampled from population..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you can take the values given to be the true population parameters.

You are not looking for 
$$P(6 < \bar X <8)$$
since this generally for a *larger* sample sizes, meaning $n\geq 2$.
You are looking for 
$$P(6<X<8),$$
which I guess you could say $n = 1$.

You can check to see that the final answer is $0.3801842$.